# React Prop Becomes Undefined on Re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I'm currently working on learning react.js, and I've run into an issue I haven't been able to move past.

So, the broad stroke is that I have a container which is meant to render a grid of images. If you select one of the images, you'll be able to change it to another image from a list of options.

Here is the potentially relevant portion of the Grid container which is rendering fine at this moment. If the full code in context helps, you can find it here: https://codepen.io/KrisSM/pen/wvvmoqg

```
 _onBrigadePosSelection = slot => {
    console.log("This was the division selected in Brigade Grid: " + slot);
    this.props.onBrigadePosSelected(slot);
  };

  render() {
 for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      //each block is a separated so that they can be rendered as different rows in the return
      if (i <= 4) {
        rowOne.push(
          <div key={i}>
            <ImageButton
              btnType={"Grid"}
              imageSrc={this.props.icons[this.props.brigadeDesign[i]]}
              clicked={() => this._onBrigadePosSelection(i)}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }

      if (i > 4 && i <= 9) {
        rowTwo.push(
          <div key={i}>
            <ImageButton
              btnType={"Grid"}
              imageSrc={this.props.icons[this.props.brigadeDesign[i]]}
              clicked={() => this._onBrigadePosSelection(i)}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }

      if (i > 9 && i <= 14) {
        rowThree.push(
          <div key={i}>
            <ImageButton
              btnType={"Grid"}
              imageSrc={this.props.icons[this.props.brigadeDesign[i]]}
              clicked={() => this._onBrigadePosSelection(i)}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

So, when an image button is selected, it fires the onBrigadePosSelection function, which returns the selected button to the container for the grid where this function is then hit.

```
onBrigadePosSelected = slot => {
    this.setState({ selectedDivision: slot });
    console.log("This is the selected division: " + slot);
  };
```

So, thus far, everything works. The grid renders and when a button is hit, this console log correctly states which button was hit. But this is where things start to get odd. When the state changes, their is a re-render of course, but after that re-render, selectedDivision becomes undefined.

[image]

Comment: Division is capitalized in the second console.log you highlighted. Is that a fluke of some kind or is it coming from a different log?

Comment: What is the value of slot parameter before the setState statement.

Comment: Where is the return statement in your render function?

Comment: Basically you are rendering an Array of JSX ? You should consider splitting rowOne, rowTwo and so on into own components. It's never advised to write a function to do this. As this is already what you are doing when writing a functional component.

Comment: Please post full code in codepen. Your parent component is missing in codepen.

Comment: One of those logs happen on line 93, the other one on line 52. Sorry but we cannot help you without providing the full code. The codepen provided doesnt contain the full code as well.

Comment: @BrianThompson That actually directed me to the answer. I was checking the value in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your codes, I think the problem comes from these lines:

```
clicked={() => this._onBrigadePosSelection(i)}
```

The reason is that `i` will keep changing for each iteration, but `() => this._onBrigadePosSelection(i)` is dynamically called function.

It means that whenever you click the button, it'll get the latest value of `i` (or garbage or `undefined`) because `i` was garbage collected already.

I would suggest you pass the function `this._onBridgePosSelection` as `props` and call it inside the `<ImageButton />` component instead.

```
<ImageButton
              btnType={"Grid"}
              imageSrc={this.props.icons[this.props.brigadeDesign[i]]}
              index={i}
              onBrigadePosSelection={this._onBrigadePosSelection}
            />
```

Then inside `<ImageButton />` component, you can call it with this:

```
this.props.onBrigadePosSelection(this.props.index)
```

Comment: This may be the issue. I'd need to make a new component because ImageButton is used in many different places, but if that's the issue, then that will need to be what I do. I'll let you know how it goes.